# Problem with mysql volume container within docker in a vagrant vm

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, vagrant

I create a repository to create a laravel app quickly: https://github.com/salvatore-esposito/laravel-dockerized

The problem is that when I use within Ubuntu everything is ok, whereas within win10 with Vagrant i have this issue with the db service:

mysqld: [Warning] World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored.

db     | mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)

db     | 2019-08-20T19:37:09.823482Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010095] [Server] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files

db     | 2019-08-20T19:37:09.831212Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

db exited with code 1

What's the matter with Vagrant?

Comment: `chmod 0444 /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: I have problems with owners not with permissions.I saw that docker use vagrant user by default, so I changed owners in Vagrant file,  directory by directory. My problem now is that in my VM I have no mysql user for /var/lib/mysql so that is a problem.

For /etc/mysql/my.cnf I solved creating a synced folder with root user and group, by I don't have a mysql user inside VM. How can I solve this?

Comment: I solved the problem setting a mysql user and group by vagrant with the same ids, and it starts. But when I use a container the mysql.sock disappear. Why?

Comment: same problem, I'm running vagrant box (ubuntu) with docker on it.When I provision the app at first time everythink is ok: migrations are passing , database is created the app is working.If i stop the vm and start it again the mysql docker container complains about "[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
" and the permissions of the mysql volume are:
vagrant@vagrant:/var/www/sc$ ls -l .docker/databases/mysql/mysql
ls: cannot access '.docker/databases/mysql/mysql/server_cost.ibd': Permission denied
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? columns_priv.frm